# Auto create txt file in subfolders

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a directory with thousands of subfolders in them. I want to create a text file in each folder containing the folder name in it.

This is the code so far:

```
@ECHO OFF
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /ad /b /s') do (
   @echo %%~nxa > %%a\test.nfo
)
```

The only problem is it can't read chinese/special characters. How can I fix this? this is on windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't any personal experience with this feature, but I believe I remember reading that the simple FOR as well as FOR /R preserve unicode characters.

```
@echo off
for /d /r %%F in (*) do echo %%~nxF >"%%F\test.nfo"
```

You might also have to enable unicode output with CMD /U:

```
@echo off
for /d /r %%F in (*) do (cmd /u /c echo %%~nxF)>"%%F\test.nfo"
```

But unfortunately CMD.EXE does not put the unicode header bytes at the top of the file.

Comment: @Ruriko - I am curious - Was the CMD /U needed?